# Как передавать пустой массив через extern С++?

Tags: c++

Есть заголовочный файл и 2 cpp файла.
Если в заголовочном сделаю

```
extern double mas[3];
```

Потом в первом си файле

```
double mas[3] = {0, 1, 2};
```

То во втором могу нормально обращаться к элементам.
Но если объявлю в заголовочном вот так:

```
extern double *mas;
```

Потом в первом в самом начале:

```
double *mas;
```

И в одной из функций уже через malloc выделю под него память и заполню. А потом обращусь к функции из второго файла. В этом случае он получается передается незаполненный и не с выделенной памятью под него. Как это правильно сделать, чтобы можно было использовать заполненный  во втором файле?

Comment: *"И в одной из функций уже через malloc выделю под него память и заполню. А потом обращусь к функции из второго файла. В этом случае он получается передается незаполненный и не с выделенной памятью под него."* - вместо мутного словесного описания следует предоставить [mcve]. Собственно использование extern глобальных переменных говорит о том, что вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: А как можно передать значение полученное в функции одного файла в функцию второго файла? Практически только вот в это залез и первое что нагуглил сделать через extern

Comment: Добавляйте в функцию соотв. аргумент.

Comment: Нужно без этого. Функция paintGL без переменных в составе

Comment: Тогда у вас проблема XY, рассказывайте в вопросе, что вы там пытаетесь сделать на самом деле.

Answer (score 3):

Что-то вы говорите, но не договариваете. По вашему описанию:

**ext.h**

```
extern double * mas;
```

**1.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ext.h"
double * mas;
void func1()
{
    mas = malloc(3*sizeof(double));
    mas[0] = (mas[1] = (mas[2] = 3) + 1) + 1;
}
void func2();
int main()
{
    func1();
    func2();
}
```

**2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ext.h"

void func2()
{
    printf("%lf %lf %lf\n",mas[0],mas[1],mas[2]);
}
```

Скомпилировано VC++ без единого замечания, на выходе

```
5.000000 4.000000 3.000000
```

Что я делаю не так?

Что делаете не так вы, сказать не могу, вы же свой код не показываете...